# jQuery - Add / Remove Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="show-content-1 hidden">
    content 1
</div>

<div class="show-content-2 hidden">
    content 2
</div>

<div class="show-content-3 hidden">
    content 3
</div>  

<div class="switch-content">
    <a id="content-1" href="#">link 1</a>
    <a id="content-2" href="#">link 2</a>
    <a id="content-3" href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.switch-content a').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.show-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hidden', '');

    $('.show-' + $id).removeClass('hidden');
    $('.show-' + $id).addClass('animated fadeIn');
    $('div[class*=show]').not($class).addClass('hidden');
    $('div[class*=show]').not($class).removeClass('animated fadeIn');
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {display:none}
```

Using the code above, if I click on Link 2, the content 2 will show - which is good.

But clicking on Link 2 once again, will hide Content 2 and nothing wont be shown. Is there a way to prevent second click or keep showing Content 2 no matter how many times Link 2 is clicked?

Comment: Seems to be working fine: [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5e878ccx/)

Comment: Off topic: you should not prefix your variables with `$` if they are not jQuery objects. You should reserve this prefix for jQuery objects only.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the content has the `hidden` class and don't touch it if it does:

```
$('.switch-content a').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
      id = $this.attr('id'),
      $content = $('.show-' + id);

    if (!$content.hasClass('hidden')) return;

    $content.removeClass('hidden').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    $('div[class*=show]').not($content).addClass('hidden');
    $('div[class*=show]').not($content).removeClass('animated fadeIn');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrtxtufz/

Comment: and also you can use toogleClass('hidden')

Comment: @Balder True... `toggle` though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use "data" to prevent clicking again.

```
$('.switch-content a').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).data('clicked')) return;

    var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.show-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hidden', '');

    $('.show-' + $id).removeClass('hidden');
    $('.show-' + $id).addClass('animated fadeIn');
    $('div[class*=show]').not($class).addClass('hidden');
    $('div[class*=show]').not($class).removeClass('animated fadeIn');

    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

Comment: This prevents further clicking on another link after first click is made.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jQuery object instead of its class, to avoid any problem :

```
$('.switch-content a').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $content = $('.show-' + $(this).attr('id'));

    $content.removeClass('hidden').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    $('div[class^=show]').not($content).addClass('hidden').removeClass('animated fadeIn');
});
```